# iOS device availability dependent on provided screenshots?

Tags: ipad, screenshot

I recently submitted an update for my iOS app, and decided not to include screenshots for iPad. Does this mean my app won't show up in the iPad App Store? Can my app get rejected because of this? Or is there an option in Xcode which controls this behavior?

EDIT: If it helps to know, the binary I submitted is marked "iPhone" not "Universal"

Comment: I don't know what the app store will do, but you are _supposed_ to provide screenshots for _every_ listed device type / screen size on which your app can run. Not doing what you are supposed to do when you submit your app is kind of risky.

Comment: If it helps to know, the binary I submitted is marked "iPhone" not "Universal" @matt

Comment: Then what you did is fine. You can't take a screenshot on iPad because you don't run on iPad (except in emulation mode, but this is actually a form of running on iPhone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your app runs on is a fact built into the app. It has nothing to do with externalities on iTunes Connect.